# Optimize filter() to stop after take limit reached

Tags: javascript

I have created the following code to search and page through an array:

```js
let data = ['banana1','banana2','apple1','apple2','apple3','apple4','apple5','apple6','apple7','apple8','apple9','apple10','apple11','apple12','strawberry1','strawberry2','strawberry3','strawberry4','strawberry5'];

let searchTerm = "app";
let skip = 1;
let take = 2;
let skipped = 0;
let taken = 0;

var filtered = data.filter( (item, index) => {
  if(taken >= take) return false;
  if(item.includes(searchTerm)){
    if(skip > skipped++) return false;
    taken++;
    return true;
  };
  return false;
});

console.log(filtered);
```

It works but once the take limit is reached if will keep looping for entire array.

Is there a way to exit filter when take limit is hit or a different more efficient way to write this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsbench.me/hvkp7kkuhq/1

A for loop is about 87% slower than this solution (meaning this is ~8x faster):

You could use `Array.some`, and push items onto the array until it the length equals `take`:

```js
let data = ['banana1', 'banana2', 'apple1', 'apple2', 'apple3', 'apple4', 'apple5', 'apple6', 'apple7', 'apple8', 'apple9', 'apple10', 'apple11', 'apple12', 'strawberry1', 'strawberry2', 'strawberry3', 'strawberry4', 'strawberry5'];

    let result = [];
    let searchTerm = 'app';
    let skip = 5;
    let take = 2;

    data
      .some((item, index) => (
        index >= skip && item.includes(searchTerm) && result.push(item), 
        result.length == take
    ))
    console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't stop iterating through all elements with `.filter` without throwing an error, which is super ugly. If you want something like that, use a loop you can `break` or `return` from.

```js
let data = ['banana1', 'banana2', 'apple1', 'apple2', 'apple3', 'apple4', 'apple5', 'apple6', 'apple7', 'apple8', 'apple9', 'apple10', 'apple11', 'apple12', 'strawberry1', 'strawberry2', 'strawberry3', 'strawberry4', 'strawberry5'];

const doFilter = () => {
  let searchTerm = "app"; // make these into arguments...
  let skip = 5;
  let take = 2;

  const filtered = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (i >= skip && data[i].includes(searchTerm)) {
      filtered.push(data[i]);
      if (filtered.length === take) return filtered;
    }
  }
  return filtered;
}
console.log(doFilter());
```

Or use `.filter` and `.slice` it afterwards - this is extremely unlikely to be a performance bottleneck, after all, code readability is usually more important.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exit filter, you don't want to filter.
Filter is exactly to iterate the entire array, "filtering" it.

What you want is more like a search... a simple for loop, forEach, while or something else can do what you want and the efficiency is not worse than using filter.

Your code will also be easier to understand because using a Filter that will not behave like a Filter will just be confusing and, let's say, inappropriate.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let data = ['banana1','banana2','apple1','apple2','apple3','apple4','apple5','apple6','apple7','apple8','apple9','apple10','apple11','apple12','strawberry1','strawberry2','strawberry3','strawberry4','strawberry5'];

let searchTerm = "app";
let skip = 5;
let take = 2;

var filtered = data.slice(skip)
    .slice(0, take)
    .filter(item => item.includes(searchTerm))

console.log(filtered);
```

I think a better overview of your use case would be better but to just `filter()` what you want you can manipulate the array before with `slice()`. In case of no `searchTerm` you would end up with an empty array.

Comment: `slice` [does not alter the original array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice#description).  And you need to switch your second slice and filter lines, right now it will only match items between `skip` and `skip + take`, if you searched for `'straw'` you would get no matches

Comment: right now it will only match items between skip and skip + take, if you searched for 'straw' you would get no matches - this is exactly what OP wants